# Using a spare laptop speaker instead of a motherboard POST speaker?

Tags: audio, speakers, motherboard, headphones

I disassembled my motherboard speaker last year, i don't recall why.

just now my motherboard seems to have died in the middle of high power gaming the rest of the PC seems fine.

I have an old laptop from which i took out a 2 gram speaker and wired it instead of a mainboard speaker. It makes no sound.

I am presuming that is a fair test that the motherboard is dead, because a motherboard speaker sound is just an oscillator sending a 4-5 volt sinewave to the speaker, So the mainboard pins should work with any headphones and small speakers?

Comment: Did you test the speaker still even works at all after potentially jamming 5 volts through it?

Comment: I checked the motherboard speaker signal with a multimeter and plugged in an old motherboard speaker that is probably defunct and i plugged in a new speaker that comes from a working laptop, i didn't get a signal on all three, and i wonder if the brand new laptop speaker should have produced any sound at all. I figure any speaker under 2 watts should produce a physical reaction from the mainboard if the mainboard works. The pc rebooted into a black screen with no post. i have to see if it's mainboard or graphics or psu.

Comment: I ll be able to reply as soon as i have a new motherboard. problem found. mini resistor cracked with bubble in it.